# Meteor cursor counts and forEach

Tags: meteor, meteor-publications

I need to add `min` and `max` fields into collection items in publish function and filter items by this fileds. I found the solution by using `forEach` for cursor:

```
Meteor.publish 'productsWithMinMax', (filter, options) ->
    Products.find(filter, options).forEach (p) =>
        p.min = Math.min p.price1, p.price2, p.price3, p.price4
        p.max = Math.max p.price1, p.price2, p.price3, p.price4

        if p.min && p.max && (p.max < p.mainPrice || p.min > p.mainPrice )
            @added "products", p._id, p

    Counts.publish @, 'numberOfProductsWithMinMax', Products.find(filter), {noReady: true}

    @ready()
```

But now `Counts.publish` returns wrong count for my cursor. How to count my cursor in this case?

Comment: Is it critical that only the documents meeting the max/min/mainPrice criteria  be published? If not, it seems like it would be easier just to publish all of the matching products and then use transforms/helpers on the client to determine which ones you need (as a bonus, this also gives you reactivity).

Comment: @DavidWeldon thank you for idea. I have about 3k of products in collection. Will it be ok to publish it all?

Comment: Probably not - that's hitting a limit where your user experience will likely suffer. I assumed that `filter` would reduce the set to some smaller initial size - is that not the case?

Comment: @DavidWeldon the main criteria is max/min. I also use skip/limit options to paginate my output. Looks like the only way to add min/max to the collection fields.

Comment: What I'm asking is this - the user says "I want products that look like X, with a limit of Y, skip Z". So now we are talking about at most Y documents. What if you publish all Y (forget the min/max stuff). Then on the client you just display all those that match the min/max criteria. Would that work? What I'm trying to do is avoid the publication transform.

Comment: @DavidWeldon no, it doesn't work. All Y documents should match both criteria (filter and min/max) at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution i've found is to add max/min properties to collection model.

P.S. It's will be nice if someone suggest a better one.